# Change tabs when any button on data table is clicked

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to tweak the following code to change tabs when any button on data table is clicked. The error message says that a button parameter is missing, which i can't find.  My ultimate goal is to use these buttons to filter related data and display in another tab. Please take a look. Thank you for your time.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(DBI)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
    title = "Examples of DataTables",
    tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("tab 1", DT::dataTableOutput("tab1"), verbatimTextOutput('printMsg')),
        tabPanel("tab 2", DT::dataTableOutput("tab2")),
        tabPanel("tab 2", DT::dataTableOutput("tab3"))
    )
    
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    printText <- reactiveValues(run_id = '')
    
    buttonInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
        inputs <- character(len)
        for (i in seq_len(len)) {
            inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
        }
        inputs
    }
    
    vals <- reactiveValues()
    
    #vals$Data <- data.table(
    vals$Data <- data.table(
        
        Brands = paste0("Brand", 1:10),
        Forecasted_Growth = sample(1:20, 10),
        Last_Year_Purchase = round(rnorm(10, 1000, 1000) ^ 2),
        Contact = paste0("Brand", 1:10, "@email.com"),
        
        'Lane Summary' = buttonInput(
            FUN = actionButton,
            len = 10,
            id = 'button_',
            label = "+",
            onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"lastClick\",  this.id)'
        )
    )
    
    
    output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT = vals$Data
        datatable(DT, escape = F)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$lastClick, {
        selectedRow <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$lastClick, "_")[[1]][2])
        printText$run_id <<- paste('clicked on ',vals$Data[selectedRow,1])
        #change tabs
        updateTabsetPanel(session, "dataset",
                          selected = "tab 2")
        
    })
    
    output$printMsg <- renderText({
        printText$run_id
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `session` in your `server` function as an argument, then it works. The use of `session` is not mandatory due to legacy reasons, but now recommended. In your case, you need it because `updateTabsetPanel` uses the `session` object:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  tabsetPanel(
    id = 'dataset',
    tabPanel("tab 1", DT::dataTableOutput("tab1"), verbatimTextOutput('printMsg')),
    tabPanel("tab 2", DT::dataTableOutput("tab2")),
    tabPanel("tab 2", DT::dataTableOutput("tab3"))
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  printText <- reactiveValues(run_id = '')
  
  buttonInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    inputs
  }
  
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  
  #vals$Data <- data.table(
  vals$Data <- data.table(
    
    Brands = paste0("Brand", 1:10),
    Forecasted_Growth = sample(1:20, 10),
    Last_Year_Purchase = round(rnorm(10, 1000, 1000) ^ 2),
    Contact = paste0("Brand", 1:10, "@email.com"),
    
    'Lane Summary' = buttonInput(
      FUN = actionButton,
      len = 10,
      id = 'button_',
      label = "+",
      onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"lastClick\",  this.id)'
    )
  )
  
  
  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT = vals$Data
    datatable(DT, escape = F)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$lastClick, {
    selectedRow <- as.numeric(strsplit(input$lastClick, "_")[[1]][2])
    printText$run_id <<- paste('clicked on ',vals$Data[selectedRow,1])
    #change tabs
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "dataset",
                      selected = "tab 2")
    
  })
  
  output$printMsg <- renderText({
    printText$run_id
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: if there are multiple pages (20 brands) in DataTable printTest$run_id returns the wrong row number.  Do you know why? Thx

Comment: @user3781528 did you adjusted the `len` argument of `buttonInput` when creating the data to the correct size? If this is not the problem, I don't know and you should ask a new question.

Comment: Yes, thanks. One more related question if you don't mind? `output$tab1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
        {
        DT = vals$Data
        datatable(DT, escape = F)
    },
    rownames=F,
    selection='single',
    filter='bottom')` Why is table formatting  not working when i add buttons?

Comment: I'm not sure, please ask a new question